# What is so topological about topological phase transitions?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-order, topological-phase, superfluidity

I am studying the KT-transition, which is called a topological phase transition. The phase transition is driven by vortices in a 2-D superfluid, where it is shown that at a critical temperature $T_c$ free vortices are energetically favoured over vortex-antivortex pairs.

There is no spontaneous symmetry breaking in this phase transition. Instead it is called a topological phase transition. However, in my very naive understanding of topolopy (obtained from looking at donuts and pretzels and stuff), we are interested in the structure, or the singularities of the system. Even in the case of the transition where these dislocations/vortices/singularities become free, the number of singularities doesn't necessarily change. I would say that the topology is conserved, since only the distance between the singularities is changed.

If the topology of the system doesn't change, why do we call it a topological phase transition?

Comment: My feeling is that the most general meaning of "topological phase transition" is "cannot be described by spontaneous breaking of a local symmetry".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let us consider a quantum phase transition (at T=0) from an ordered phase to a disordered phase, driven by the quantum fluctuations of the order parameter. We like to ask if the disordered phase has [topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_order) or not.

The importance of the topological defects in phase transitions have been emphasized by Kosterlitz and Thouless, who shared 2016 Nobel prize (with Haldane) ``for theoretical discoveries of topological phase transitions and topological phases of matter''.

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.09394), we show that the phase transitions driven by
fluctuations with all possible topological defects produce disordered states
that have no [topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_order), and correspond to non-topological phase
transitions.  While transitions driven by fluctuations without any topological
defects usually produce disordered states that have non-trivial topological
orders, and correspond to topological phase transitions.
If we refer to phase transitions induced by  topological defects as *topological* phase transitions, and refer to phase transitions between different
topological orders as **topological** phase transitions, then our result can
be restated as:

> in general *topological* phase transitions are not
> **topological** phase transitions, nor are **topological** phase transitions  *topological* phase transitions.

Thus, it may be confusing to refer to the transition driven by topological defects
as a topological phase transitions, since the appearance of topological defects
decrease the chance to produce topological phases of matter.